# Unity - doing a raycast from a C# is affecting all instances of prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have the following C# attached to a prefab in Unity3d:

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Tile") && hit.collider.gameObject.name == gameObject.name)
                {
                    Debug.Log("You clicked a tile");
                    Debug.Log("The game object you hit is:" + hit.collider.gameObject.name);

                    Rigidbody rigidBody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                    rigidBody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
                    //hit.rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(5000, hit.collider.ClosestPoint(hit.point), 5.0f, 0.0f);
                    rigidBody.AddForceAtPosition(ray.direction *200, hit.collider.ClosestPoint(hit.point));

                }
            }
        }

    }    
}
```

If you notice, I had to compare both the hit object's Tag, but also verify that the object's name also matches the name of the object to which the script is attached to, otherwise, all Instances of this prefab on the scene were affected simultaneously. Why does this happen?  The Debug.Log() ouput shows that only one collider is being hit with each click, so why are other instances of this prefab being affected?

Comment: When your prefab contains component code it will be triggered for all instances of that prefab. If you have multiple in the scene, as you say, then you are sending as many rays out as there are instances. If that's not what you want, then the other instances shouldn't even be sending out a ray to begin with (for starters, it would be wasteful and potentially laggy), so you would need some code logic to handle that. For instance, to have a component like "rayDetector" which you only add to a single instance, or some kind of bool within your component. What are yoy trying to do, actually?

Comment: It would make more sense to have this script only **once** in your scene and from there check which object you hit. Currently **every instance** of this script does its own raycast ... You might want to rather use [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) in order to only track clicks on one single instance

Comment: Yes, having  the ray sent out in a OnMouseDown() event inside each individual instance proved correct. Now I don't have to validate object name and CPU use is down as well. Thanks.